# How to Fix Right Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

I am Trying to make Left Outer Join Use bellow code;
The Result Using (LEFT OUTER , RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER And INNER JOIN) is The same Result.
I am Try to return All Publisher Name Include Those who don't connected with any Books yet!

```
SELECT P.PublisherName,
    COUNT(B.BookID) AS BookPublished
    FROM LR_Publisher AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN LR_Book As B 
    ON P.PublisherID = B.PublisherID
    WHERE (P.PublisherID = @pPublisherID OR @pPublisherID IS NULL)
    GROUP BY PublisherName
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The query looks fine (provided `PublisherName` is unique, i.e. there are no two publishers with exactly the same name). It should return all publishers with their book counts, no matter if it's ten, thousand or zero books. What's the issue? How is the query's result different from what you want?

Comment: In LR_Book I have only PublisherID

Comment: And you use it to join to `LR_Publisher`. What's wrong with that? Seems perfect to me.

Comment: hmmmm.. that what I need to understand; it seems perfect for me also! but it dose not give me the result I need

Comment: Can you add some data as example? Current records on both table and expected result.

Comment: So again: How is the query's result different from what you want? By the way: You should qualify the `PublisherName` in `GROUP BY` with the table alias: `GROUP BY P.PublisherName` (but that would only be an issue if `LR_Book` contained a `PublisherName` too, which would be a flaw in the database design.)

Comment: PublisherID       Publisher Name
   1                 DarMarefa
   2                 DorManthor
  3                Alneser

Comment: Add some sample data and an expected result, because the query has to work well.

Comment: Don't post sample data in the comments. Edit your request and put it there.

Comment: Thankk You Alot Guys ; Mr Alexander Volok  Answer Work At the End

Comment: So should yours.

Comment: Yes I Try it again and it Work Mr. Thorsten Kettner.. It seems I were have a Problem  in my SQL Server!!!!
,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Publishers that have no books published are filtered out by `GROUP BY`. 
It can be fixed by using `GROUP BY ALL`:</strike>

```
SELECT P.PublisherName,
COUNT(B.BookID) AS BookPublished
FROM LR_Publisher AS P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LR_Book As B    ON P.PublisherID = B.PublisherID
-- WHERE (P.PublisherID = @pPublisherID OR @pPublisherID IS NULL)
GROUP BY PublisherName
```

Comment: While this solves the OP problem, please note that the ALL keyword in the GROUP BY is for backward compat. It's bound to be removed in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for your effort; I try your code and it give same if replace LEFT OUTER JOIN  or RIGHT OUTER JOIN  or INNER JOIN.. not give me the result I need

Comment: @Samar.Abdeen, can you comment entire WHERE clause and try again? `--WHERE (P.PublisherID = @pPublisherID OR @pPublisherID IS NULL)`

Comment: @Samar.Abdeen, Manfred Wippel answer is also correct and more preferable alternative

Comment: @EzLo, thanks, your point is correct, Manfred's answer solves this issue

Comment: Yes it Workkkkkk; Finallly; 1 Million Thank You

Comment: `ISNULL` is superfluous, as `COUNT` can never return null. And `ALL` in `GROUP BY` should be superfluous too, because the left outer join already sees to it that publishers without books are shown.

Comment: In the end, it appears that OP has ONLY to remove his WHERE clause to get the right resultset

Answer (score 1):

you could write it this way

```
select P.PublisherName,
       isnull(bi.BookPublished, 0) as BookPublished
from LR_Publisher as P
    left join (
        select B.PublisherID, Count(B.BookID) BookPublished
        from LR_Book as B 
        where (@pPublisherID is null or B.PublisherID = @pPublisherID)
        group by B.PublisherID
    ) bi on P.PublisherID = Bi.PublisherID
where (@pPublisherID is null or P.PublisherID = @pPublisherID)
```

I also was not aware of the filtering done by group by. Thank you for the question.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Manfred Wippel

Answer (score 0):

simple left join will help you  want all publisher name including who does not published any book yet

```
   SELECT P.PublisherName 
    FROM LR_Publisher AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN LR_Book As B 
    ON P.PublisherID = B.PublisherID
```

Comment: I need to return all publisher who published and not published yet(both of them)

Comment: @Samar.Abdeen answer eidited it will return all publisher name including published or not published book

Comment: not work! it replay the name of publisher.. I mean if this publisher publish 4 books; it give me the name of publisher 4 time